# Panda data frame, group by and sort string data based on its integer representation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda data frame from a csv file, that looks roughly like this:

```
   col1 col2
   1    12937
   10   8932
   1    9090
   11    7171
   11   12392
   3    6262
   2    9123
   11   9872
   3    4321
```

I want to group them based on the value in col1, I am currently using `df.groupby('col1',sort=True)`. However, since I read the data from csv, the col1 are in string format, therefore the resulting sort is roughly like this:

```
    col1 col2
1:  1    12937
    1    9090
10: 10   8932
11: 11   7171
    11   12392
    11   9872
2:  2    9123  
3:  3    6262
    3    4321
```

I want it to be sorted based on its integer value. How can I do it?

Comment: The CSV reader should have converted the strings to numbers. You can still fix this by `df.col1=df.col1.astype(int)`

Comment: Ah, I tried that, I forgot to reassign the data frame. That works though :)

Comment: I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSV reader should have converted the strings to numbers. You can still fix this by `df.col1=df.col1.astype(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

While working with dataframes if your numeric columns have been read as strinigs, you can convert all the columns to `int` or `float` type using -

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
```

This will try to convert all columns to numeric and ignore the columns which cant be converted to numbers.

**EDIT**

You might want to be careful while using this. It can change the dtype of column that could perhaps be representing a categorical variable.